# Locker Puzzle in Java

Tags: java, beginner

The author of my book does not release odd-numbered solutions to students, so I can't check my solutions. I was wondering if there was a better way to solve this problem without simply printing out the square roots.

Here is the question:

> (Game: locker puzzle) A school has 100 lockers and 100 students. All
>   lockers are closed on the first day of school. As the students enter,
>   the first student, denoted S1, opens every locker. Then the second
>   student, S2, begins with the second locker, denoted L2, and closes
>   every other locker. Student S3 begins with the third locker and
>   changes every third locker (closes it if it was open, and opens it if
>   it was closed). Student S4 begins with locker L4 and changes every
>   fourth locker. Student S5 starts with L5 and changes every fifth
>   locker, and so on, until student S100 changes L100.
>
> After all the students have  passed through the building and changed
>   the lockers, which lockers are open? Write a program to find your
>   answer.
>
> (Hint: Use an array of 100 Boolean elements, each of which indicates
>   whether a locker is open (true) or closed (false).  Initially, all
>   lockers are closed.)

Here is my solution:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean[] lockers = new boolean[101];
        //Open all multiples of 1 before moving on to 2
        for (int i = 1; i < lockers.length; i++) {
            lockers[i] = true;
        }


        //open every locker for every multiple of i
        for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; i * j <= 100; j++) {
                lockers[i * j] = (lockers[i * j] == true) ? false : true;
            }
        }

        //Display the indices of the open lockers
        for (int i = 0; i < lockers.length; i++) {
            if (lockers[i] == true)
                System.out.println("locker " + i + " is open.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You are using `i = 1` as a special case, when in fact that can be handled by your other code already:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; i * j <= 100; j++) {
        lockers[i * j] = !lockers[i * j];
    }
}
```

---

However, to be more readable, I suggest changing the inner loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j <= 100; j += i) {
        lockers[j] = !lockers[j];
    }
}
```

Now it reads as "Start `j` at `i`, repeat as long as `j` is less than or equal to 100, increase `j` by the value of `i`"

Comment: You really should suggest that they start from 0 and go to 99. Java arrays start at zero, so they are creating a 101 element array, not a 100 element array.

Comment: In this case I think the 101 element array is a good choice, as it improves readability.  The array index can be the number of the locker instead of having to shift by 1.

Answer (score 14):

> ```
> lockers[i * j] = (lockers[i * j] == true) ? false : true;
> ```

This line makes no sense at all.  There are two red flags to me.

1. Comparing to `== true` is just sort of bad in general.
2. Using a ternary when the two possible options are `false` and `true` is always going to be unnecessary.

We can rewrite this as simply:

```
lockers[i * j] = !lockers[i * j];
```

---

> ```
> if (lockers[i] == true)
>     System.out.println("locker " + i + " is open.");
> ```

Again, using `== true` is problematic.  `lockers[i]` is a `boolean`, so simply `if (lockers[i])` will suffice.  But there are other problems with this.

**If** you insist on omitting braces (which I can **never** recommend), we should move the executed line on to the same line as the `if`.  This makes it less likely to write in some logic error if we ever want to add code here.

So, if you *must* omit the braces, we should write:

```
if (lockers[i]) System.out.println("locker " + i + " is open.");
```

But I think it's better to just add the braces:

```
if (lockers[i]) {
    System.out.println("locker " + i + " is open.");
}
```

But alternatively, *here* might be a place to use our ternary if we want to print the status of *all* of the lockers.  Eliminate the `if`:

```
System.out.println("locker " + i + " is " + (lockers[i] ? "open" : "closed"));
```

Answer (score 10):

You've used a 101-element array instead of a 100-element array, which is fine.  However, in that case, you should avoid mentioning `lockers[0]` altogether.  The printout loop should be:

```
for (int i = 1; i < lockers.length; i++) {
    if (lockers[i]) {
        System.out.println("Locker " + i + " is open.");
    }
}
```

It would be better to avoid hard-coding `100` as a loop limit, and compare against the array length instead.

I suggest renaming the `lockers` to `lockerIsOpen`, so that the true=open, false=closed convention is self-documented.

Answer (score 7):

After the "game" completes, the open (true) lockers will be exactly those lockers whose number is a perfect square.  [(Proof.)](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Locker_Problem)  Therefore, you can eliminate both the the O(N<sup>2</sup>) loop nest and the O(N) workspace:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i*i <= 100; i++)
            System.out.println("Locker " + (i*i) + " is open.");
    }
}
```

If I were going to hand this in as an answer to a homework problem, I would include the proof in a large comment above the code, to make clear *why* this is an answer to the question posed.

If I were going to *assign* this as a homework problem I think I would make it a two-part question: first, do it the obvious way with an array and two loops; second, there's a way to do it in linear time and constant space, find out how and prove it's reliable.

Note 1: Hardwiring the upper limit is a bad code smell.  Ideally, one would accept the upper limit as a command-line argument.  I don't actually speak Java and therefore I don't know how to do that (specifically, I don't know what exactly will be in `args[]` or how to convert a string to a number and check for overflow).

Note 2: Formally unnecessary parentheses around the `i*i` on the `System.out.println` line are there because string-concatenation `+` is not mathematical addition, so readers might hesitate to assume that the precedence of `*` is higher.

Note 3: Curly braces were omitted around the one-line loop very much on purpose.

Comment: This is probably missing the point of the programming exercise though. And after reading the first paragraph of the question again, specifically what the OP didn't ask for. ;)

Comment: `the optimal program for this problem looks like this`: Well... It depends on what you mean with `optimal`. From memory usage and executable size that is probably true. For optimal CPU usage something like `print("Locker 1 is open.\nLocker 4 is open.\nLocker 9 is open...")` probably turns out to be better ;-).

Comment: @ABoschman I *guess* that might be what the OP meant by "printing out the square roots"?  It doesn't jump out at me.

Comment: @yankee If I knew how (I don't actually know Java) I would have written this program to read the upper limit as a command line argument.  Maybe that should be a third note, come to think of it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Starting with `i=1` is not needed.
2. `s=0` is the first student, so he will hop one by one i.e. s+1.
   Similarly, `s=5` is the 6th student and he will hop for 6 i.e. s+1.
3. To display the results use, `x+1`, to show last locker as 100 (not 99).
4. use `boolean` instead of `Boolean` to avoid nulls.
   otherwise use `(LockerList[l]==null||LockerList[l]==false)?true:false;` to toggle.
5. As a personal preference, use `LockerList` instead of `Lockers` in a very large project. Code readability is important.
6. Do not use `foreach` because you have to change the inner values.

```
public class MainClass{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        boolean LockerList [] = new boolean [100];
        
        for (int s=0; s<100; s++)                 // student loop
            for (int l=s; l<100; l=l+(s+1))       // locker loop
                LockerList[l] = !LockerList[l];   // toggle

        // print open lockers
        for (int x=0; x<100; x++)
            if (LockerList[x] == true)
                System.out.printf("Locker %d is open\n", x+1);
    }
}
```